# Group binary bits together

Tags: python, binary, bit-manipulation

I have a list of numbers (here is an example with 4-bits numbers, but I want to do it with 16-bits integers) :

```
L = [0b1000,0b1100,0b1111,0b1001, 0b0000]
```

and I want to group all 1st bits together, then all 2nd bits together, then all 3rd bits together, etc., like this:

```
out = 0b11110011000010000110
```

This solution (proposed by @markcial) works :

```
print [[a[i] for a in [format(b,'04b') for b in L]] for i in range(4)]
#[['1', '1', '1', '1', '0'], ['0', '1', '1', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '1', '1', '0']]
```

but I would like to avoid string formatting to do these binary operations.

**How to group bits together without using string formatting ?**

Comment: Can you still use some string methods to later convert the result into an integer? Or not strings at all?

Comment: @PauloBu, if possible I would like to avoid strings : using a string character for every bit manipulation is like multiplying by 8 the memory usage (8 bits used for every string char)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this algorithm suits your needs, I will explain it with 4 bits digits and you can later expand it to be used with 16 bits.

```
L = [0b1000,0b1100,0b1111,0b1001, 0b0000]
bits = 4  # total bits
next_bit = bits*len(L)-1  # next position to be calculated
res = 0

for i in range(bits-1,-1,-1):  # iterate 3,2,1,0 (bits backwards)
    for x in L:                # iterate through every integer in L
        res = res | (((x&1<<i)>>i)<<next_bit)  # say what? o.O
        next_bit-=1            # set next_bit to the next position to be calculated

 >>> bin(res)
'0b11110011000010000110'
```

Basically, what it does is iterate through every bit position to be analize in each number, then iterate through each number to analyze that position, and once you know what position to analyze on what number, you perform this weird calculation: `(((x&1<<i)>>i)<<total_bits-1)`.

The loop will accumulate on `res` the result of that calculation which I explain:

1. `x&1<<i` will test if the bit at position `i` is on
2. `((x&1<<i)>>i)` shifting backwards `i` bits will make sure the result is `1` or `0`
3. `(((x&1<<i)>>i)<<next_bit)` shifting forward `next_bit` will set the bit to `1` or `0` at position `next_bit`.

You need this `next_bit` integer to keep account of what's the next bit on the result you need to set. Since you have for example, 5 four bits digits, you know the result will have 5*4 bits.

I don't like much those two for loops. In C this is probably good but in Python they are not very efficient. I still thinking a way to remove them. I dare you to benchmark them with this simple oneliner:

```
>>>L = [0b1000,0b1100,0b1111,0b1001, 0b0000]
>>>int(''.join(['1' if x&1<<i else '0' for i in range(3,-1,-1) for x in L]),2)
995462
```

You'll be surprised about the performance.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks so much! I'm trying to understand how it works... Is there a way for storing the output as binary data into bytes (i.e. each time we have 8 bits, we pack this into a char/byte) so at the end we have an (unreadable) bytes-string  ?

Comment: Hmmm, don't understand quite what you're trying to do. On the first algo we're calculating a number, that number can be packed into 8 bit chars by doing some bit twiddlings as well. I think there's also some modules in python `array` or `struct` that help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to collaborative work with @PauloBu, here is what I was looking for (I admit my question was a bit unclear) : the output numbers are packed into bytes (8-bits) for easy writing into a file :

```
import struct
L = [0b1000,0b1100,0b1111,0b1001, 0b0000]
bits = 4
res = 0
processed_bits = 0
s = ''
for i in range(bits-1,-1,-1): 
    for x in L: 
        res = res | (((x&1<<i)>>i) << (7-processed_bits))  
        processed_bits += 1           
        if processed_bits == 8:
            s += struct.pack('B', res)
            res = 0
            processed_bits = 0

with open('blah.bin', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(s)
```